# Aiogram, как вытащить переменную message.text. Входящее сообщение от пользователя

Tags: python, aiogram

Aiogram, как вытащить переменную message.text. Входящее сообщение от пользователя.
Мне нужно вытащить текст входящего сообщения поместить его в переменную. И использовать далее.
При выводе print (message.text) после await работает правильно.
Но мне нужно именно вне данной функции.
Ошибка:

```
print (message.text) NameError: name 'message' is not defined

    @dp.message_handler(commands="avito")
async def cmd_avito(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Введите ссылку вашего товара")
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, message.text)
```

Comment: Может вы более подробно объясните для чего это вам? Ибо вряд ли в с этого хендлера получите что-то кроме `avito`

Comment: В дополнение к предыдущему комментарию, можно после Вашего хандлера запустить "машину состояний", и дальше работать с ней. Но, всё таки нужно понимать что дальше будет происходить с "отловленным сообщением".

Comment: Отловленное сообщение мне нужно, для того что бы получить ссылку, и вставить ее в selenium  для дальнейшей работы.

Comment: Ну так просто в хендлере вызовите функцию для запуска селениума

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто сделай переменную message глобальной